# C++ Issue Reading Text File

Tags: c++, text

I'm trying to pick up C++, and am getting the error below, when reading a text file. Any idea why?

Input:

```
This is a test.
    A test, with tabs  and too many spaces.
If this is a good one,
    then all will be well.
```

Output:

```
    then all will be well. too many spaces.
```

Code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {    

    string line;

    ifstream infile ("A5.txt");

    if (infile.is_open()) {
        while (!infile.eof()) {
            getline(infile,line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
        infile.close();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lose the `while(!infile.eof())` construct.  It's also known as the "Pascal disease".  In C/C++, eof() is *not* true until you read *past* the end of file, and so you will call getline() *one too many* times.  `while( getline( infile, line ) )` is the idiomatically correct way to write such loops.

Comment: I second @arayq2 s comment, and further it to say given *this* program's construction, you can also lose the `if (infile.is_open())` and simple move directly from `ifstream infile ("A5.txt");` to the `while( getline( infile, line ) )` loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use an implementation that uses UNIX line endings (`\n`), and interprets `\r` to return the cursor to the beginning of the line. The file contains old Mac OS line endings (`\r`), which means that `getline()` reads till the end of the file and puts all the `\r` into the string, causing you to print them later to the console.

Comment: how did you figure out that OP created a text file on MacOS-9? :) the `\r` hypothesis is a bit shaky imho

Comment: @akira: this is the only possible explanation I can think of assuming the system is functioning properly. The OP can use a Hex viewer or count the number of times the loop is executed to verify it. ⋮)

Comment: `\r` itself is a valid theory, but not the "old macos" .. i would rather think that netbeans fiddles around with the output. printing out `\r` would indeed yield described behavior; imho its the output or the interpretation of the output, not the input that is the problem here.

Comment: Very odd. So how would I get around this problem?

Comment: Brilliant analysis.  The carriage returns (and lack of linefeeds) are causing each line to overwrite the previous one.

Comment: @Adam_G: depends on what you consider a problem. Is changing the file considered OK? Then save a file in a text editor that writes out `\n` line endings. Do you have to support only files with `\r` for line endings? Use `getline(infile, line, '\r')` to specify a different separator. Do you have to support any files without changing them including other line endings, like `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n`? Then you cannot use `getline` and have to write your own function to read lines terminated by any of these (or implement your own `codecvt` facet that does the conversion).

Comment: Got it. I had tried the delimiter with `""` around it, which caused an error. Just needed the single quotes, i.e. `'\r'`